# Sorting MongoDB Results

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I have the following structure in MongoDB (is an example structure):

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 4e465de048177e8105000003
        )

    [id_usuario] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 4e43b20648177e5305000000
        )

    [mensaje] => lero lero si?
    [created_at] => MongoDate Object
        (
            [sec] => 1313234400
            [usec] => 160000
        )
    [comentarios] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [comentario] => hola mundo
                [usuario] => [_id] => MongoId Object
                    (
                        [$id] => 4e465de048177e8105000003
                    )
                [created_at] => MongoDate Object
                (
                    [sec] => 1313234400
                    [usec] => 160000
                )
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [comentario] => hola mundo
                [usuario] => [_id] => MongoId Object
                    (
                        [$id] => 4e465de048177e8105000003
                    )
                [created_at] => MongoDate Object
                (
                    [sec] => 1313234400
                    [usec] => 160000
                )
            )
        )
)
```

I want to get the last 10 comments sorted by created_at in descending and I write the following:

```
$db->usuarios->find()->sort(array('created_at' => -1))->limit(10)->skip(0);
```

(this is PHP code driving MongoDB)

Could anyone help me to do the same but also display the last 3 comments ordered by created_at in descending?

Is that possible in a single query? Can you help with code please?

Comment: It's logical: sort in ascending order and fetch the first three (equivalent to last three in descending order).

Comment: ¿? I mean, if you can get the last 3 comments 10 comments that are consulted initially and all in one go Is that possible? - yo me refiero a que si se puede sacar los ultimos 3 comentarios de los 10 comentarios que se consultan inicialmente y todo eso en una misma consulta ¿eso es posible?

Comment: Please post in english only. [Stack Overflow is meant to be used in English only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: On another note, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know php well enough to understand the document structure you have described. So I am assuming that the `comment` documents are "embedded" in your `usuario` documents.

If it is true, then you cannot address the `comment` documents directly. You will have first fetch a `usuario` document. With that you will get an array of `comment` documents which you will have to sort and filter on the client side.

Or if your comment objects are stored in a particular order you can use the $slice to fetch the first 3 or first 10 or any such subset. More info : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the last 10 comments sorted by created_at in descending and I write the following:
>
> ```
> $db->usuarios->find()->sort(array('created_at' => -1))->limit(10)->skip(0);
> ```

That query returns the last 10 usarios (users) and all of their comments:

To get the last 3 comments you have to sort by `'commentarios.created_at'` and then filter those results. Like this:

```
$user = $db->usuarios->find()->sort(array('commentarios.created_at' => -1)->limit(3);
$comments = array_merge($user[0]['commentarios'], $user[1]['commentarios'], $user[2]['commentarios']
$ordered = uasort($comments, 'sorter')

function sorter($a, $b) {
  return $a['created_date'] < $b['created_date'];
}
```

Notice that find returns 3 users **and** their comments, so you have to find the 3 most recent between those users.